# python-docxで振り仮名が存在するか調べる方法

Tags: python, python3, windows, python-docx

python-docxモジュールでdocxファイルからテキストを抽出しています。
そこで1つ質問なのですが、テキスト内に振り仮名（ルビ）が存在するかどうかを調べることはできるのでしょうか。
また、もし調べることができたとして、そのルビの内容を取得するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。
何かご存知でしたら教えていただけると幸いです。
環境はWindows10、Python3.7です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このあたりの情報から探れるのでは？[(OOXML) ルビ周りのメモ](https://niszet.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/01/02/230847)、[Run-level content - python-docx 0.8.9 documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/run-content.html)、[python-docx/ref/rnc/wml.rnc](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/e784a73bfcdc24ba08f772055f8b4240f420adcf/ref/rnc/wml.rnc)、[Word docxファイルの中身を探検する - Office Open XML ざっくり入門](https://qiita.com/sky_y/items/2ab80adfb7a998e47239)、[Ruby Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.ruby?view=openxml-2.8.1)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。なかなか難しそうですが、もうちょっと頑張ってみます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

本家SOの関連質問[Use Python docx to create phonetic guide / 'Ruby text' in Word?の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56690499/8248751)では、「`python-docx`はルビの読み込みに未対応」の回答が寄せられています。

現時点の[`python-docx`ドキュメント](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)を読んでも、ルビを取得する方法は見つかりませんでした。

ただし`python-docx`の機能を使って、コメントの[(OOXML) ルビ周りのメモ](https://niszet.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/01/02/230847)に記載されているOOXMLを直接解析して振り仮名を調査・抽出することは可能です。

下記のサンプルコードでは、3つの方法を使って振り仮名を抽出しています。
[Run](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#run-objects)ごとに振り仮名を調査・抽出する場合は、コード内の`3.`の方法を参考にしてください。

**サンプルコード**

```
from docx import Document

with open('sample.docx', 'rb') as f:
    document = Document(f)

print("# 1. ドキュメントのルビを表示する")
for t in document.element.xpath("//w:ruby/w:rt/w:r/w:t"):
    print(t.text)

print("# 2. ドキュメントのルビと本文を表示する")
ns = document.element.nsmap
for ruby in document.element.xpath("//w:ruby"):
    r = ruby.xpath("w:rt/w:r/w:t", namespaces=ns)[0].text  # namespaces を指定しないと "lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix" が降りかかる
    t = ruby.xpath("w:rubyBase/w:r/w:t", namespaces=ns)[0].text  # namespaces を指定しないと "lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix" が降りかかる
    print(f"{t}《{r}》")

print("# 3. runs のルビと本文を表示する")
for p in document.paragraphs:
    for run in p.runs:
        ruby = run._r.xpath("w:ruby")
        # runに振り仮名が存在するか調べる
        if ruby:
            r = run._r.xpath("w:ruby/w:rt/w:r/w:t")[0].text
            t = run._r.xpath("w:ruby/w:rubyBase/w:r/w:t")[0].text
            print(f"{t}《{r}》")
```

参考資料:

- [Word文書の構成](https://gammasoft.jp/support/how-to-use-python-docx-for-word-file/#doc-struct)
- [(OOXML) ルビ周りのメモ](https://niszet.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/01/02/230847)
- [トホホな疑問(13) Python、lxml、デフォルト名前空間とXPath](https://jhalfmoon.com/dbc/2019/10/20/%E3%83%88%E3%83%9B%E3%83%9B%E3%81%AA%E7%96%91%E5%95%8F13-python%E3%80%81lxml%E3%80%81%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E7%A9%BA%E9%96%93%E3%81%A8xpath/)
- [python-docxにおける下線・傍点・フリガナの処理](http://cup.sakura.ne.jp/use_markdown/ue_ruby.html#session-ex11)

  - 振り仮名を追加したい場合はこちらが参考になります